# Javascript not allowing for static variable to be updated each time on click

Tags: javascript, static

I am trying to make it where when the user clicks the demo section toggles the flag value each time.

I was under the impression that the static variable was myFunction.flag and it would remain constant throughout the page each time it changes...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Search a string for "w3Schools", and display the position of the match:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "Visit W3Schools!"; 
    var n = str.search(/w3Schools/i);
    myFunction.flag = 1;
    if(myFunction.flag){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFunction.flag;
    myFunction.flag = 0;
   } else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFunction.flag;
    myFunction.flag = 1;
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, it's the same property everywhere. However you probably want to put the initialisation `myFunction.flag = 1;` outside of the function so that it does not run every time the function is called…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new variable each time a click happen.

Just make it global.

```
<script>
 var flag = 0;
function myFunction() {
    var str = "Visit W3Schools!"; 
    var n = str.search(/w3Schools/i);
    if(flag){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFunction.flag;
    flag = 0;
   } else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFunction.flag;
    flag = 1;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Static != global

Comment: @Bergi Yes. Gave a thought about it. Withdrawn that.